# Thymeleaf not recognizing Strings just ModelAndView

Tags: thymeleaf

According to documentation like [this](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-2-using-thymeleaf/) I should be able to do this...

```
@RequestMapping("")
public String root(){
  return "test";
}
```

However, this just returns the word "test". In order to get it to work I have to use the slightly more explicit...

```
@RequestMapping("")
public ModelAndView root(){
  return new ModelAndView("test");
}
```

What little thing am I missing that is preventing the top version from rendering properly?

Comment: On your class, are you using `@Controller` (and not `@RestController`)?

Comment: If you're trying to return `"test.html"` when you call the root, you'd probably want `@GetMapping("/")` instead of `@RequestMapping("")`

Comment: @Metroids I am using RestController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`.

`@RestController` is the equivalent of doing:

```
@RequestMapping("")
@ResponseBody
public String root(){
  return "test";
}
```

Which is saying to return the result of the `root()` function as a json/xml object (which means just returning the string test).  If you want "test" to represent the page to render, use `@Controller`.